# How to show that these presheaves are sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

For $X$ any topological space, show that the following presheaves of sets over $X$ are in facts sheaves:

Fixing an open $V \subseteq  X$, let

$$  h_V(U)=  \quad \begin{cases}
\text{singleton}  & U \subseteq V\\
\emptyset & U \nsubseteq V \\
\end{cases}
$$

Solution: Both the monopresheaf and the gluing condition are meaningless for $U \nsubseteq V$, so they trivially hold. For $U \subseteq V$ both conditions are valid as there is only one possible section. Therefore all restrictions and gluings are well-defined.

My question is: could please any one explain to me how I can justify my answer in more detail?

Comment: You have the right intuition, so just write down the definitions and proceed as usual. Take an open covering, assume the sections agree on the overlap, which implies only a few cases, etc.